# "I'll explain (about) where I live" -- is "about" needed or desirable here?

Tags: word-usage

> 1. I'll explain about where I live.
> 2. I'll explain where I live.

which one is correct?

Comment: With 'about'. So you are to explain the environment, the climate, the plants, etc. where you live? Without 'about', it sounds as if you are to give a person the directions how the same would reach the place where you live.

Answer (score 2):

I'll explain about where I live.

I'll explain where I live.

You don't usually use the preposition "about" after the verb explain.  The use of "about" seems redundant in the first sentence.  So the second sentence is preferable; the sentence is quite clear without "about".

Sometimes, you need to use "about" in order for the sentence to sound cleat and natural such as "I'll explain to you about him/George".

Answer (score 0):

## Both are correct, but not quite the same.

"I'll explain where I live": this says to me that you are about to tell me how to locate your home.

"I'll explain about where I live": this says to me that you are going to tell me some information about your home. It *could* be how to locate it, but it could be something else, like its size, its colour, or the interesting story about how you came to live in a museum basement.